# Mobile and Web API

Tags: php, zend-framework2

We have a requirement to create an API for IOS , Android and Web App.We have a plan to create the API using PHP and Zend Restful API and the web App using zend MVC.

My Question is
We need to work web app same as like mobile apps. So is it possible to access the REST API from my web MVC in Zend? it is good approach or can i write separate model class for web app?

Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes... go with codeigniter its good

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can design your web app and your API to consume the same business/services layer. You need separate the services layer well enough and treat your web app controllers and API controllers as consumers of the services layer.

Also please read about Zend's [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) which will help you do the same with lesser efforts.